# a is a tensor of shape: (19, 19, 5, 80). How to print different slices of it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

`a` is a tensor of shape `(19,19,5,80)`. Created as below:

```
a= tf.random_normal([19, 19, 5, 80], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
```

How do I print/view slices or individual elements of this multi-dimensional array?

Comment: `r = a.eval()`. And then print `r`?

Comment: If the provided answer answers your question, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

In pure tensorflow:

```
    In [1]: a[1, 2, 3, 4].eval(session=sess)
    Out[1]: 2.1795652
```

In numpy:

```
    In [1]: a_np = a.eval(session=sess)

    In [2]: a_np[1, 2, 3, 4]
    Out[2]: 2.1795652
```

You can basically treat a tensor like a numpy array, with the difference that tf has a session to run operations.